# How do I create a tag using SVN in XCode 5?

Tags: xcode, svn

I used to be able to do this in XCode 4 when using git, but since then our company has moved to SVN and I've also updated to XCode 5. I see that in the repository configuration there is an option of where to point to in the repository for tags, but I don't see any way of actually creating a tag. I thought maybe I could go into the configuration and point branches to the path of tags, create my tag, then change back, but it seems awful hacky.

Obviously, I know I can do this via command line or other third party SVN tool, but I would first like to determine if XCode is capable of doing this before I add another tool or process to the mix.

I've scoured the less than helpful XCode documentation on the developer site without any luck. Hopefully someone here can help me out.

Comment: Searching around it does not seem to be possible